# Pass custom calculated product price to cart in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I have calculated a custom price within the single product page using jquery and have output it as a totalCost variable. How can I use this value and overwrite or pass it through to the checkout to be able to use this new price as the product price?

I would post some code but I really dont have a clue where to start. Examples ive seen just set a global price override in the functions file.

Many thanks.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thank you this helps me start in the right direction. I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

**First step:**

You should need to add a custom hidden field, where you will pass your calculated price:

```
// Adding a custom imput hidden field in add to cart form
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_hidden_product_field', 11, 0 );
function custom_hidden_product_field() {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_price" class="custom_price" value="">';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**Then you will need to pass your calculated price with jQuery in this hidden input field,** *(or to make your calculation inside this function and set the value directly in this hidden input field)*.

> The complete code: [Set cart item price from a hidden input field custom price in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303818/set-cart-item-price-from-a-hidden-input-field-custom-price-in-woocommerce-3/52304377#52304377)